# Docker Compose v3 and link environment variables

Tags: docker-compose

[Link environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/) has been deprecated since v2. What is the alternative for discovering the random port then? I have a dockerized java app that I can inform about data source via environment variables but now I can not. The vague mention that I should use `link name` is not helping. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

So here is thing `--link` use to create so many unnecessary variables which were not required at all.

Now when you use docker-compose you can name your service anything you want. So if you are running mysql, you can name it mysql or db or dbservice or anything.

In your configs you can either use the service name `mysql` or `db` or `dbservice`. Or you can use environment variable inside the code to pickup the service name and pass that through your docker-compose.

Also you can have alias for the same container with different names.

About the ports, if I have a nginx image which exposes port 8080. Then I know in my config that it will always be port 8080 and hence no need to pass it